# How to convert @Html.ActionLink to a button using bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index","Auction", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
</div>
```

This is my code, and I want it to work as a button, but this is not working for me.

Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

Comment: It could be because there are no route values. See if this works. `@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Auction", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-green"  })`

Comment: I don't think  `btn-green` is a bootstrap class. Check bootsrap docs for mode details, but `btn btn-success` should work.

Comment: this was my mistake ( btn-green)  but i already tried as btn-success, this is not working.

Comment: Check that your bootstrap CSS is linked correctly, as `btn btn-success` is the bootstrap class for a green button. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/

Comment: Did you add bootstrap in your page or layout page

Answer (score 0):

The `@Html.ActionLink` generates an HTML anchor tag, therefore, your code would be something like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="/Auction/Index">Back to List</a>
```